# Loading tensorflow model from checkpoint does not update parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to load a (trained) tensorflow model from a previously saved checkpoint, using the code below.

```
model = MyModel()
# Load trained model from checkpoint.
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer, net=model)
manager    = tf.train.CheckpointManager(checkpoint, "./myModel", max_to_keep=1)
checkpoint.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)
```

Although, this runs without any problems, the model I am ending up with does not seem
to contain any of the stored parameters from the trained model.
The losses before and after running  `checkpoint.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)` 
are equal. If someone could help with my (most likely) very stupid problem, it would be amazing. Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Your model doesn't init from checkpoint  , you init a new one , right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. This how I understood it. I initalized an new none and then using the checkpoint and the manager I am loading the parameters in from a saved checkpoint.

Comment: You should load the weight use ```model.load_weights(checkpoint)```